# FirebaseListObservable filter

Tags: arrays, angular, filter, observable, angularfire2

I am looking for a way to filter a firebaselistobservable. I have code like the following

```
<div>
  <a *ngFor="let lis of list | async" (click)="onSelect(lis)" >
    {{lis.name}}
    </a>
</div>

this.list = this.fb.getList('Instructors');
```

What i want to be able to do is once the list of instructors is loaded be able to type into a text box and as i type the names of the instructors will filter. I am having a lot of trouble figuring out a way to filter a firebaselistobservable, which in this case is my list. If anyone has a method to achieve this it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the filtering on the client, just add a filter pipe to your ngFor directive. In angular2 it is not offered out of the box, but there are plenty available.